# Debugging javacard applet with wireshark

Tags: wireshark, javacard

So I'm on Ubuntu debugging a conversation to my javacard applet by using wireshark USB capture. I'm actually trying to determine the best data rate I can achieve.

My test app (on PC) only constructs a couple of APDUs: one to send and one to receive, and I can see these in wireshark. However I get a load more traffic going on than I expect. I think this may well be down to my ignorance of what is going on can anyone elaborate?

Sub question, does anyone know of a dissector that will decode the APDUs?

Comment: APDU's are specified in ISO 7816-4. It's a terribly bad but shallow specification, you can just look at the first 4 bytes to determine the kind of APDU that is send (CLA, INS, P1 & P2). Probably you are seeing a lot of low level communication with the reader, not much else.

Comment: Yup, that is what I'm doing, just a pity I cannot filter on it :)  ...I guess I will need to research those lower level protocols if I am going to figure out what is going on. Just that the turn around time at the lower level is a couple of ms and in the application is 10's of ms - is this the expense of going through the kernel?

Comment: Nope, that is the speed of the reader, the smartcard and probably the speed of the connection to the smart card. Kernel time is relatively high compared with high spped operations, but compared to smart card ops it should be negligible.

Comment: I've also looked at the ATR which would appear that the card has reported approx 20k Bytes/sec ... so I might see if there is a better card, thanks for chatting!